# after using Scroll reveal js i am having problems with text overflowing on top of everything

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, overflow

i have this problem where when i use the scroll reveal js (https://scrollrevealjs.org/) in my website every text element i apply the effect overflows on top of every other element and i cant find a fix for it no matter how much i try please someone help me with this. in the screen shot i have attached you can see that when i open the menu the paragraph below the menu is overflowing over the menu and the navbar, i have tried using z-index but nothing really worked.i am new to stack overflow so if i made any mistakes please forgive me.ANY HELP WILL BE GREATLY APPRECIATED.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!--=============== FAVICON ===============-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="media/logo.png" type="image/x-icon" />

    <!--=============== BOX ICONS ===============-->
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!--=============== SCROLL REVEAL ===============-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@4.0.0/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>

    <!--==================== GOOGLE FONTS ====================-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!--=============== CSS ===============-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />

    <!--=============== META TAGS ===============-->
    <meta name="title" content="STUDIO 69" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Studio 69 Architects is a Bangalore-based architectural practice with a strong focus on design. After several years of working with some of India’s respected architectural firms, Ganesh Kumar established Studio 69 Architects in 1995. Since then, Studio 69 has completed a number of successful projects across India-ranging from residential, commercial, civic projects as well as interiors. Our team are experienced, innovative, and committed to achieving an outstanding result for every project. We treat every project with great important regardless how small, large, simple, or complex. We are determined to ensure that the completed design and built project satisfies the client’s needs, objectives an aspirations. The founding principle of Studio 69 is to address human needs through built form. We design to cater to the requirements of the client by curating a functional and aesthetical environment that are commercially smart."
    />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <title>Studio 69</title>

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script
      async
      src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=__________"
    ></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag("js", new Date());

      gtag("config", "__________");
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main class="main">
      <!--==================== HEADER ====================-->
      <header class="header">
        <nav class="nav container">
          <a href="#" class="logo"
            ><img src="media/logo.png" alt="studio-69-logo"
          /></a>
          <div class="navMenu">
            <ul class="navList">
              <a href="#home" class="navLink" onclick="closeMenu();"
                ><li class="navItem">Home</li></a
              >
              <a href="#" class="navLink" onclick="closeMenu();"
                ><li class="navItem">Studio</li></a
              >
              <a href="#" class="navLink" onclick="closeMenu();"
                ><li class="navItem">Projects</li></a
              >
              <a href="#" class="navLink" onclick="closeMenu();"
                ><li class="navItem">Contact</li></a
              >
              <i
                class="bx bx-toggle-left"
                onclick="toggleTheme(); closeMenu();"
              ></i>
              <i class="bx bx-x" onclick="closeMenu();"></i>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <i class="bx bx-menu" onclick="openMenu();"></i>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <!--==================== HOME ====================-->
      <section class="home" id="home">
        <div class="homeHeader">
          <h1 class="homeTitle">STUDIO 69</h1>
          <h3 class="homeSubtitle">Architecture at its Finest</h3>
        </div>
      </section>

      <!--==================== ABOUT ====================-->
      <section class="section container about">
        <div class="aboutHeader">
          <h1 class="aboutTitle">About us</h1>
          <p class="aboutPara">
            Studio 69 Architects is a Bangalore-based architectural practice
            with a strong focus on design. After several years of working with
            some of India’s respected architectural firms, Ganesh Kumar
            established Studio 69 Architects in 1995. Since then, Studio 69 has
            completed a number of successful projects across India-ranging from
            residential, commercial, civic projects as well as interiors. Our
            team are experienced, innovative, and committed to achieving an
            outstanding result for every project. We treat every project with
            great important regardless how small, large, simple, or complex. We
            are determined to ensure that the completed design and built project
            satisfies the client’s needs, objectives an aspirations. The
            founding principle of Studio 69 is to address human needs through
            built form. We design to cater to the requirements of the client by
            curating a functional and aesthetical environment that are
            commercially smart.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <!--==================== COURSES ====================-->
      <section class="section container"></section>

      <!--==================== TESTMONIALS ====================-->
      <section class="section container"></section>

      <!--==================== CONTACT ====================-->
      <section class="section container"></section>

      <!--==================== FOOTER ====================-->
      <section class="section container"></section>

      <!--=============== SCROLL UP ===============-->
      <a href="#home"><i class="bx bx-chevron-up"></i></a>
    </main>

    <!--=============== MAIN JS ===============-->
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
/*=============== VARIABLES CSS ===============*/
:root {

  /*========== Colors ==========*/
  --primary-color: #141414;
  --secondary-color: #FFFFFF;
  --accent-color: #0046d2;
  --small-width: 94%;
  --medium-width: 90%;
  --big-width: 76%;

  /*========== Font and typography ==========*/
  --big-font-size: 2rem;
  --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
  --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
  --h3-font-size: 1rem;
  --normal-font-size: .938rem;
  --small-font-size: .813rem;
  --smaller-font-size: .75rem;

  /*========== Font weight ==========*/
  --font-regular: 400;
  --font-medium: 500;
  --font-semi-bold: 600;
  --font-bold: 700;
}

/* Responsive typography */
@media screen and (min-width: 968px) {
  :root {
    --big-font-size: 3.5rem;
    --h1-font-size: 2.25rem;
    --h2-font-size: 1.5rem;
    --h3-font-size: 1.25rem;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
    --small-font-size: .875rem;
    --smaller-font-size: .813rem;
  }
}

/*=============== BASE ===============*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  background: var(--secondary-color);
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  transition: .2s;
  z-index: 10000000;
}

body,
button,
input,
textarea,
p {
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.bx {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*=============== THEME ===============*/
body.darkTheme {
  --primary-color: #FFFFFF;
  --secondary-color: #141414;
}

/*=============== REUSABLE CSS CLASSES ===============*/
.section {
  padding: 70px 0px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .container {
    max-width: var(--small-width);
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: var(--medium-width);
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    max-width: var(--big-width);
  }
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.main { 
  overflow: hidden;
  /*For animation*/
}

/*=============== HEADER ===============*/
.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
}

.logo {
  width: 130px;
}

.sticky {
  background: var(--secondary-color);
  padding: 10px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  transition: .2s;
}

.header.sticky .navLink {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  transition: .2s;
}

.header.sticky .bx-toggle-left {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.header.sticky .bx-toggle-right {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.header.sticky .bx-menu {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.header.sticky .navLink:hover {
  color: var(--accent-color);
  transition: .2s;
}

/*=============== NAV ===============*/
.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navLink {
  color: white;
}

.navList {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  column-gap: 50px;
}

.bx-toggle-left {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.bx-toggle-right {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.bx-x, .bx-menu {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navList {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: var(--secondary-color);
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 40px;
    padding: 40px 40px;
    border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
  }

  .navLink {
    color: var(--primary-color);
    font-size: var(--h2-font-size);
  }

  .bx-toggle-left, .bx-toggle-right {
    color: var(--primary-color);
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  .bx-x {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  .bx-menu {
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
  }
}

/*=============== HOME ===============*/
.home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),
    url("../../media/bg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.homeHeader {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.homeTitle {
  font-size: var(--big-font-size);
}

.homeSubtitle {
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

/*=============== ABOUT ===============*/
.aboutHeader {
  text-align: center;
}

.aboutTitle {
  font-size: var(--big-font-size);
}

.aboutPara {
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
}

/*=============== COURSES ===============*/


/*=============== TESTMONIALS ===============*/


/*=============== FOOTER ===============*/


/*=============== SCROLL BAR ===============*/
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px;
  background: #141414;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #404040;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

/*=============== TO-TOP ===============*/
.bx-chevron-up {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 60px;
  right: -200px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--accent-color);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

/*=============== RESPONSIVE BREAKPOINTS ===============*/

/* For small devices */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .container {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .header {
    padding: 20px 5px;
  }

  .header.sticky {
    padding: 5px 5px;
  }
}

/* For medium devices */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}

/* For large devices */
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

```js
/*=============== CHANGE HEADER BACKGROUND ===============*/
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  const header = document.querySelector("header");
  header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
});

const menu = document.querySelector(".navList");
function openMenu() {
  menu.style.right = "0";
}

function closeMenu() {
  menu.style.right = "-100%";
}

/*=============== SHOW SCROLL UP ===============*/
const toTop = document.querySelector(".bx-chevron-up");
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 100) {
    toTop.style.right = "30px";
  } else {
    toTop.style.right = "-100px";
  }
});

/*=============== DARK LIGHT THEME ===============*/
const themeToggle = document.querySelector(".bx-toggle-left");
function toggleTheme() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("darkTheme");

  if (document.body.classList.contains("darkTheme")) {
    themeToggle.classList.add("bx-toggle-right");
    themeToggle.classList.remove("bx-toggle-left");
  } else {
    themeToggle.classList.add("bx-toggle-left");
    themeToggle.classList.remove("bx-toggle-right");
  }
}

/*=============== SCROLL REVEAL ANIMATION ===============*/
const sr = ScrollReveal({
  origin: "top",
  distance: "60px",
  duration: "2000",
  // reset: true
});

sr.reveal(".homeTitle, .homeSubtitle", {});

sr.reveal("", {
  interval: 100,
});

sr.reveal(".aboutPara", {
  origin: "left",
});

sr.reveal(".aboutTitle", {
  origin: "right",
});

sr.reveal("", {
  origin: "bottom",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably fixed the problem by now, but i´m gonna leave the solution that worked for me in case anyone needs it.

Just apply overflow-x hidden in your body.